# Symfony2 whitescreen and no logs

Tags: git, symfony, screen

Yes, that is what happens on my local MAMP when I switch to my master branch (the visual GIT interface form MAC, application called GitHub). For a branch a few days behind called prod it works fine.

Odd!?

It is as if the `app.php/app_dev.php` never gets run but encounter an error...

**Actions taken:**

I have deleted the cache folders between the branch switching, also cleared browser cache (seen that in chrome that sometimes creates a hiccup with several symfony2 installation on now machine).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked php.ini to make sure it has the `error_reporting` configuration set to show all errors?

Comment: I believe I have found the problem. Like you said, error reporting was probably off on that machine, I am currently on a linux machine (which has error reporting on) and it tells me bootstrap.php.cache is missing (and indeed it was erroneously added to the gitignore earlier today)

Comment: correction - that file SHOULD be in the gitignore, but was somehow deleted as it was added to the gitignore, therein was my problem.

Comment: So I have not been able to verify on that particular machine yet, but if this is indeed the case - why does symfony2 not write any log files at all when error reporting is turned off - doesn't symfony2 to some extend have it's own error reporting? Or is it fully based on the webserver error reporting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As advised by Ken above, I turned on error reporting and confirmed what I had already concluded - the bootstrap file was missing.

Comment: Also here's a great 2-step guide how to turn error reporting on with MAMP http://gilbert.pellegrom.me/enable-php-error-reporting-in-mamp